# What is a good way to create non-flaky performance tests

Tags: c#, benchmarking, performance-testing

I have written a few commonly-used methods where I've found that performance is quite important. After making several changes to fix noticeable performance bugs, I like to put some tests in place to verify that the performance does not degrade due to future changes. However, I'm finding that these tests are often very flaky (likely due to garbage collection, other activity on our automated testing server, etc.). What I'm wondering is, is there an accepted best practice for writing and maintaining these sorts of tests?

So far, most of my tests look like the following:

```
runMyCode(); // for assembly loading/jitting
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (iterations) { runMyCode(); }
var time = sw.Elapsed;

// then either
Assert.Less(time, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(some reasonably generous amount of time));
// or
// time some other piece of benchmark code (e. g. a framework method 
// which runMyCode() layers on top of). And do:
Assert.Less(time.TotalSeconds, someMultiplier * benchmarkTime.TotalSeconds);
```

One thought I had to improve stability would be to have the test store recorded times in a database and only fail if the last N times failed the benchmark.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one).

Answer (score 4):

Look this article: [Learn how to create correct C# benchmarks](http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/dotnet/learn-how-to-create-correct-c-benchmarks/). Main tips for you case:

- You should use warm-up of processor cache for getting corrected results
- You should run code on a single processor (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1)`)
- You should set high priority for thread and process
- You should run `GC.Collect()` before benchmark
- You should run benchmark several times and take median of results

  Also you can use this free open-source .NET framework for create adequate benchmark: [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/BenchmarkDotNet).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using visual studio or mono develop but you could use speed profiler tools like:

RedGate: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CPfS1Z_k1bkCFYuk4Aoda3oAVg

or use default visual studio performance profiler.  See this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx (Much more on the internet).

Comment: As I attempt to state in my question, I'm not looking to do a single profiling run, but rather to guard against future performance degradation with an automated test. Can these tools do that?

Comment: Oh sorry for my misunderstanding. Redgate can do that. For visual studio performance profiler , I have never tried this kind of test. You can try both of it (vsp is integrated in visual studio and redgate gives you a kinda completed trial)